# Select multiple options in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html-select

how can I select multiple value in this country dropdown

this is my code:

```
function print_country(country_id) {
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
  option_str.length = 0;
  option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '');
  option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `multiple` attribute that is available for [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Also set the attribute of the selected option using selector.attr('selected', true);

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute to your existing select. It allows you to select multiple values with the CTRL button.

```
<select multiple></select>
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/cau5k9g2/2/)

Comment: it's the default behavior for selects with the multiple attribute. You can add a toggle button which shows/hides the select btn.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option.selected property like this:

```
var option_str = document.getElementById('country_id');
for ( var i = 0; i < option_str.options.length; i++ )
{
  if ( //condition for selecting the current option)
  {
    option_str.options[i].selected = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control select2 color-gray" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(".select2").select2();
```

you can download select2 plugin on github. link mention on below.
https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/develop/dist/js